# Component One Licenses.licx throws an Exception

Tags: silverlight, licensing, componentone

Hy Guys,

After we decided to buy an C1 License for the Silverlight FlexGrid Component we were wondering why the activation won't work.

The Dialog Shows up that the copy of C1.FlexGrid is activated, but however after we published our Silverlight Addin we still get the Message that C1 is not activated.

After a long time of Research we found out that no licenses.licx file was created.

So we created the file manually with the following entry:

```
C1.Silverlight.FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid, C1.Silverlight.FlexGrid.5
```

Afte Rebuilding the whole solution we get an Invalid-Cross threat Access Exception right from the licenses.licx file.

```
Error   1   Exception occurred creating type 'C1.Silverlight.FlexGrid.C1FlexGrid, C1.Silverlight.FlexGrid.5, Version=5.0.20131.311, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***************' System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Re-looking at the Xaml I saw following Piece of code

```
c1:LicenseMode.Evaluation="True"
```

and quickly changed it to

```
c1:LicenseMode.Evaluation="False"
```

Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

check the version of componentone dll included in your assembly, if it is same as declared in the License.licx file. If not, you have to update your license file.

Comment: It is definitely correct. I use Version 5 of the FlexGrid and in the Licenses.licx file is Version 5 referenced.

Answer (score 0):

licence.licx files doesn't make sense for Silverlight projects. If you have valid license installed on your development machine, search all your xaml and remove all instances of the C1NagScreen.Nag="True" attributes and rebuild the application.
If it doesn't help or you have other problems, please ask in our support forums: http://our.componentone.com/groups/forum/silverlight/studio-for-silverlight/ (it's absolutely free) or contact support directly: http://www.componentone.com/Support/

Comment: I have removed the licenses.licx file again and started searching for C1NagScreen.Nag="True" or some Kind of nagscreen but I don't get any matches?!

Comment: Please, ask for help in our support forums, maybe your problem is not about licensing at all.

Comment: I have already created a Ticket at C1. Hopefully they can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching the xaml for "Nag" and removing them.  They get put there when the license is not valid, but they are not cleaned automatically afterwards.  There are some threads about this on the C1 Forums, including my own!

Greg